# How to migrate `this.$nuxt.$emit` in nuxt2, to nuxt3

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm migration nuxt2 app to nuxt3.

How to migrate the following code and the pair written in nuxt2, to nuxt3?

components/sample.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
async someFnc() {
 await this.$nuxt.$emit("hoge/fuga")
 // someImpl
}
</script>
```

The pair code is as follows.

pages/sample2.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
beforeDestroy():void {
 this.$nuxt.$off("hoge/fuga")
}
</script>
```

---

Additional Info

I think this one

```
<script lang="ts">
async someFnc() {
 this.$emit('hoge')
}
</script>
```

can be migrated to, but I can't migrate the first codes.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmit(['hoge'])
const someFnc = () => {
 emit('hoge')
}
</script>
```